# Automated File / Input Stream handeling in Java

Tags: java, inputstream

Preamble: I am aware of Apache IO and would like commentary beyond pointers to Apache IO.

---

This could probably be a tad silly question but I just realized that:

When I implement an API which has to read from say an input stream I end up implementing a lot of overloaded variants, for example:

```
public void foo ( InputStream input, int somearg, float someotherarg) { ...
```

overloaded variants:

```
public void foo ( File inputFile, int somearg, float someotherarg) { ...
public void foo ( String filename, int somearg, float someotherarg) { ...
```

--OR--

I can implement

```
public void foo ( InputStream input, int somearg, float someotherarg) { ...
```

and implement helper utility functions that handle filename, files and convert them to InputStreams.

The question I have is that I keep re-implementing this -- is there a library someone has written or has this been handles in a design pattern.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/IOExplained) has this thing called `InputSupplier`. Perhaps you should take a look.

Apart from that, there is an [AutoCloseable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) interface and a feature called [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) in Java 7, which may simplify your case (i.e. you can only create API methods that require `InputStream` and programmers can use try-with-resources to handle those input streams when they have string / file parameters).

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for Apache Commons IO. It has a bunch of methods that can reduce the overhead of this sort of thing.